# How do I create multiple pages from a single markdown file?

Tags: markdown, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

In Gatsby, I have `file.md`, and I'd like to generate multiple pages—one for each section of `file.md`.

## gatsby-transformer-remark

When using `gatsby-transformer-remark`, I can get the HTML of an entire markdown file with `allMarkdownRemark.nodes.html`. How do I get the HTML of each section of the file? For instance:

`file.md`:

```
# section 1

**bold**

# section 2

foo
```

I'd like to get an array of section HTMLs, like:

```
[
  '<div><h1>section 1</h1><b>bold</b></div>', 
  '<div><h1>section 2</h1>foo</div>'
]
```

## gatsby-plugin-mdx

With `gatsby-plugin-mdx`, when do I

```
query MyQuery {
  mdx {
    headings {
      value
      depth
    }
  }
}
```

I get

```
{
  "data": {
    "mdx": {
      "headings": [
        {
          "value": "Section1",
          "depth": 1
        },
        {
          "value": "Section2",
          "depth": 1
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

But when I do:

```
query MyQuery {
  mdx(headings: {elemMatch: {value: {eq: "Section1"}}}) {
    body
  }
}
```

The `body` is the entire file, not just Section1.

Answer (score 2):

In your markdown file, the `file.md` everything that is after the `---` is the body of the markdown so directly, you can get parts of it.

I would suggest a different workaround using MDX (**M**ark**d**own + JS**X**) which allows you to add React's logic inside a markdown file.  Gatsby has a detailed plugin for that: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/

Another workaround, without using the MDX would be using "sections" inside the markdown. For example, a structure like:

```
---
title: Test
section1:
  description: some description 
section2:
    title: Some **bold title** for the section 2
---
The rest of the body content
```

Will create a node for each section, so your object will look like `allMarkdownRemark.nodes.section1.description` and `allMarkdownRemark.nodes.section2.title` respectively.

Note that you can add all the markdown supported styling along with it.

Comment: Thanks, the actual sections are very long, so don't fit well indented in frontmatter. I tried your gatsby-plugin-mdx suggestion but don't see how to get each section's content separately. Do you know how? I edited the question with my progress.

Comment: The body of an MDX is literally a JSX file, so add your components and wrap the content as you wish.

Comment: I'm not sure how adding components can enable me to generate multiple pages from a single mdx file?

Comment: No, adding components in an MDX file will allow you to customize the sections of the markdown's body

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like using `gatsby-plugin-mdx` is not a solution to my original question.